# Your Ruby version is 2.3.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm, bundler

[image]

What is just happening here? I used `gem install bundler` as well.

Comment: What does `which rake` print?

Comment: /home/rafin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/rake

Comment: Just out of curiosity what does `head -1 $(which rake)` print? However I'm guessing the problem is somewhere downstream.

Comment: gem install bundler and gems update bundler is not doing the job :(

Comment: it is showing `#!/usr/bin/env ruby2.3` . Is this something relevant with the isse?

Comment: Wtf..yes that's wrong.

Comment: Edit `/home/rafin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/rake` and change `ruby2.3` to say just `ruby`. Should fix it.

Comment: However that is an indication something else seems wrong. I would reinstall ruby-2.4.1 from scratch with rvm to make sure all is good. And then recheck the `rake` binary again.

Comment: Ok now that answer saved my day

Comment: Great........ :)

Comment: THanks a lot buddy

Comment: @Casper Maybe add it _as_ an answer? So it can be accepted and makes it easier to find ;-)

Comment: Yes...just a sec.

Comment: If you find yourself jumping between versions `bundle exec` can help too. e.g. `bundle exec rake db:create`

Comment: Thanks. Will check that out too. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect something could be wrong with your `rake` command. First we check what `rake` command your shell is choosing for you:

```
 which rake
```

From this we saw that it was running the Rake binary from the 2.4.1 RVM folder, which seems correct, but to further verify that it's using the right Ruby version we need to do:

```
head -1 $(which rake)
```

And this shows an incorrect shebang line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby2.3
```

So you need to edit `ruby2.3` to say just `ruby` here, and that will fix the problem.

However it should not have been `ruby2.3` to begin with. So perhaps a better solution is to completely reinstall 2.4.1 with RVM, to make sure the other scripts in `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/` are not affected by the same problem.